# How to Create Custom Dilaog on Button Click

Tags: java, android, xml

I am working on an application for my personal project.

I plan to have a table/chart in my application, and next to the application I plan to put a button which is what I need help with.

Could you please tell me what code I can use to create a button which when clicked:

- Creates a new window(popup or not is fine) where there is a editText
  for the users to input some text and when they are done the text is
  inserted into a cell of the table?

Maybe useless information:
My application's "table" should be borderless and maybe instead of table is list with separators between the user's text
The application is essentially a to do list but when they click the button to insert a new task it is in a new window.

Comment: I think you'r talking about about popup window. Dig a google about it. Also better to post screenshot what you want.

Comment: Remember this is a phone app!

Comment: Android is for mobile application. I know very well :)

Answer (score 0):

Create an AlertDialogBox

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext(), );
    builder.setMessage("Message")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setTitle("Title");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Todo
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Todo
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put a button in the XML code you need to fetch it by it's id in the activity (java class), then use

```
button.onClickListener( v -> {
//here you can have a code block that will be done once the button is clicked
//put Ashutosh Sagar code for the alert dialog
```

Keep in mind that you can make the dialog as you want by customizing it to your preferences. This usually requires another XML layout just for the look of the dialog and some more reading on Alert Dialog.

As it was said above by Aman, we can clearly post you the code but that way you won't learn anything. Happy coding.